# PHP Dropdown please select option

Tags: php, html

How can I use PHP to raise an error if this particular value is selected?

`<option>Please Select</option>`

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to accomplish. What do you mean by "raise an error"?

Comment: Just like any `$_POST`'ed data in PHP? give it a value and use `==` or use `empty()` and set the value of this option to nothing, like: `value=""` as shown in *atmon3r*'s answer.

Comment: May also want to look into HTML5's [`required`](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#required) attribute on the select element. Will catch some simple errors and in combination with PHP be a good experience for your user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

***HTML***

```
<select name="selectoption">
     <option value="">Please Select</option>
</select>
```

***PHP***

```
if (isset($_POST['selectoption']) && $_POST['selectoption'] == '' ) {
   echo 'Error, select an options';
   exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if `$_POST` is empty
Html:

```
<select name="category">
     <option value="">Please Select</option>
     <option value="1">Category 1</option>
     <option value="2">Category 2</option>
</select>
```

and php:

```
if (empty($_POST['category']) && isset($_POST['category'])) {
        echo 'Error, select category';
        exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a value too, and check the value in you php with `$_POST['foo']`

```
<select name="foo">
<option value="0">Please Select</option>
...
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this is better way:

```
if (isset($_POST['category']) && $_POST['category'] == '' ) {
       echo 'Error, select category';
       exit;
}
```